# JavaScript Increment Issue

Tags: javascript, syntax, logic, tracking

I've written a function that's supposed to (1) generate a random number, (2) judge a user's for that number and (3) keep track of the user's attempts.

The first two goals are done, but I'm having trouble with (3), keeping track of the user attempts.

```
function randNum(){
        var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*(100)+1); 
        var usrGuess = document.forms.guess.visitor.value;
        var attempt = 0;

        if (usrGuess != num){
            if ((usrGuess < 1) || (usrGuess > 100))
                document.getElementById("wizard").innerHTML = "Fool! This number isn't even part of the set!";
            else if (usrGuess > num)
                document.getElementById("wizard").innerHTML = "Wrong, fool! This is greater than my number! I was thinking of " + num + "!";
            else if (usrGuess < num)
                document.getElementById("wizard").innerHTML = "Wrong, fool! This is less than my number! I was thinking of " + num + "!";

            attempt += 1; // Here's the change.
            alert(attempt); // Here's the output. It doesn't change.
        }
        else if (usrGuess == num){
            if (attempt <= 5)
                document.getElementById("wizard").innerHTML = "Right... fool. You only guessed in " + attempt + " tries.";
            else if ((attempt <= 10) && (attempt > 5))
                document.getElementById("wizard").innerHTML = "Right, fool. You only after " + attempt + " tries.";
            else if (attempt > 10 )
                document.getElementById("wizard").innerHTML = "Haha, fool! You finally guessed after " + attempt + " tries.<br />Go wallow in your lost time.";
        }
    }
```

For some reason, even if I place "attempt" as an outside parameter, the number only tracks up to one attempt.

Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're declaring "attempt" as a local variable. It'll be re-initialized every time you call the function.

You're also making up a new random number on each call to the function, which seems a little mean :-)

Declare the variables outside the function and see how it goes. (Keep "usrGuess" inside however; just move "num" and "attempt".)

Answer (score 0):

You have `var attempt = 0` within the function. Each time you call this function, it will set `attempt` to 0. Declare `attempt` outside the function and see how that works for you.

Also, I prefer the following notation for increment: `attempt++;`

Comment: Well, I feel silly. I thinking in terms of C and placing "attempt" as a parameter for randNum. Taking away the prarameter makes it work (though I'm not entirely sure why).